# Identify a beige spaceship

Tags: spaceship, object-identification

This has been bothering met for quite some time. I know I have seen this ship somewhere, but I cannot remember where.

[image: Unknown ship]

Does anyone know where this ship comes from?

This image comes from this slide, I was able identify everything else on it.

[image]

Answer (score 29, accepted):

This is a [DY-100](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/DY-100_class), the same class of ship as the *Botany Bay*, which carried Khan and his followers in ["Space Seed"](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Space_Seed_(episode)) (*Star Trek* TOS 1x24):

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I knew I saw this ship somewhere in Star Trek.

Comment: _Botany Bay..._ Botany Bay! Oh no! We've got to get out of here now!